# Vuejs force rendering component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to vue, and I can not figure out how to render a component programaticaly. I'm using a javascript library : leaflet and I made a component to wrap the library. Leaflet allows to display maps and to add markers to it. To define pop-up on click, the library ask for a html content

```
...
marker.bindPopup("<h3>Title</h3>").openPopup();
...
```

instead of an html string, I'd like to use a component template to make the code cleaner. How can I force to render a component, to get the html content to pass to the bindPopup function ?

Comment: I believe this component will be more helpful than you expect: https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-2-components-for-leaflet-maps/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! However, I have hard time to make it works. I made a fiddle with a basic exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/rvxc2uLk/3/. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.$mount()` method and `VueComponent.$el` property to get html from the Vue component. like below

```
var component = new Vue({
  template: `<div>Your HTML is here...</div>`
}).$mount();
```

**CODE SNIPPET**

```js
var component = new Vue({
  template: `<div>Here is your component html</div>`
}).$mount();

console.log(component.$el);
//you can use this component.$el for you maker bindPopup
//marker.bindPopup(component.$el).openPopup();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.2/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```